# How to remove shadow and reflection on the the images in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have a question on how to remove shadow and reflection on the signboard on the images.
I have no idea abt how it is done.

I am doing coding in C#, emguCV (opencv wrapper)

I am seeking help on this issue. Thank you very much.

This is the example: (I can't post a picture cos i am a new user)
 http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/7826/reflectionshadowimages.png

Comment: What are you talking about? Could you show some examples and highlight parts of the image you want removed? Also are these parts added by C# libraries or are they on the image itself?

Comment: I wanted to show the image but i can't do so....

Answer (score 0):

We did something similiar in openCV before. We tried to get a acceptable result in photoshop and applied the same filter with openCV then. But image processing like that is no easy task, even in PS you have to be good to get nice results.

Comment: How can I do an image enhancement on these images

Potential Problem
1.Image is partially shaded 
2.Image contains reflected image on the image
3.Image too dark or too bright

The pic can be found in here (Look at the signboard)
http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/7826/reflectionshadowimages.png

Comment: play with the levels, but reflections will be hard

Comment: what do u mean play with the levels?

Comment: maybe you should get a bit into graphics before you start automated image correction :>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with filtering (e.g. Gaussian or similar) or histogram equalizing.